# Working with lists in LOGO

Tags: logo-lang

I'm trying a recursive program in ACSLogo (a mac version of Logo) and want to return a list of 2 integers (basically and X coordinate and a Y coordinate). I cannot figure out how to get it to return 2 values. It does one no problem.

Also, when you create a list and you wish to refer back to it to extract a value in a particular index,  it seems like you have to paste the list as is and you cannot refer to it by an assigned name.

Example:

```
Item 4 [1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21]
```

You cannot name that list "fibb" and refer to it like this `X + fibb item 4`

Comment: Oh wow, Logo. Haven't seen that mentioned in years, since the Apple II / Macintosh Power PC days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a list to a variable name like this:

```
Make "locations [1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21]
```

You can then access one of the items in the list like this:

```
Item 1 :locations
```

For instance, to set a variable named `x` equal to the second item, you could do this:

```
Make "x (Item 2 :locations)
```

Next, to make a new list from two different values, you can use the `List` command, for instance:

```
Make "location (List 1 2)
```

Or, from variables:

```
Make "location (List :x :y)
```

So, to get an `x` and `y` coordinate out of a list of locations and then create a new `location` variable containing both the `x` and `y` values, you could do this:

```
Make "locations [1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21]
Make "x (Item 1 :locations)
Make "y (Item 2 :locations)
Make "location (List :x :y)
```

Or, more simply:

```
Make "locations [1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21]
Make "location (List (Item 1 :locations) (Item 2 :locations))
```